# How to get disk drive informations in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, macos, disk

I was looking at the main window of Mac OSX Disk Utility and I found four informations about USB devices (when a drive item is selected):

- Disk Description
- Connection Bus
- Connection Type
- USB Serial Number

I was able to get the first three information using Disk Arbitration framework.
I got them registering a callback routine in response to new disk device detection:

```
DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(session, NULL, OnDiskAppeared, (void *)NULL);
```

The routine looked like this:

```
static void OnDiskAppeared(DADiskRef disk, void *__attribute__((__unused__)) ctx) {

CFDictionaryRef dict = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);

const void *DAMediaName = CFSTR("DAMediaName");
const void *DAVolumeName = CFSTR("DAVolumeName");
const void *DADeviceModel = CFSTR("DADeviceModel");
const void *DAMediaUUID = CFSTR("DAMediaUUID");
const void *DAVolumeUUID = CFSTR("DAVolumeUUID");    

printf("DAMediaName: ");
CFShow(CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, DAMediaName));
printf("DAVolumeName: ");
CFShow(CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, DAVolumeName));
printf("DADeviceModel: ");
CFShow(CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, DADeviceModel));
printf("DAMediaUUID: ");
CFShow(CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, DAMediaUUID));
printf("DAVolumeUUID: ");
CFShow(CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, DAVolumeUUID));

CFRelease(dict);}
```

The routine actually returned me informations about volumes and phisical drives and, in the last case, returned me the informations about the three disk properties I was talking about before.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about the fourth (USB Serial Number).

I printed the whole dictionary by calling:

```
CFDictionaryApplyFunction(dict, printKeys, NULL);
```

having coded the printKeys callback routine like this:

```
static void printKeys (const void* key, const void* value, void* context) {

CFShow(key);
CFShow(value);}
```

but no key returned me the desired fourth value.

I guess somewhere, maybe in the Disk Arbitration framework, there had to be something to provide such information but I can't figure out where.

Some advice?

Thanks for help.

Antonio